# Store values in struct's fields

Tags: c, input, struct

I need some help with saving input in a struct's field. I want two values to be stored in two fields and subtract them from other two fields of a struct that were initialized earlier:

```
...
typedef struct GPS GPS;

struct GPS  {
    float latitude;
    float longitude;
};
...
printf("Enter the location's latitude of a place you want to visit: ");
visitLocation.latitude = scanf("%f", &visitLocation.latitude);
printf("Enter the location's longitude of a place you want to visit: ");
visitLocation.longitude = scanf("%f", &visitLocation.longitude);    
...
```

I can't make it store values on those fields, could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the stored value. By default the scanf store the readed value in the location of the second parameter. So you dont need to asign it to the same variable because scanf return the number of items readed, so if your input is the number 112, scanf return 1 and you asign it to visitLocation.latitude, which overwrite the real input.

You just need to do

```
printf("Enter the location's latitude of a place you want to visit: ");
scanf("%f", &visitLocation.latitude);
printf("Enter the location's longitude of a place you want to visit: ");
scanf("%f", &visitLocation.longitude);
```

it should work. Good luck!

Comment: it does! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you call `scanf()`  for 3 variables, what do you expect for it to return?

So let's check the spec of `scanf()`:

```
RETURN VALUE
       On success, these functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned; this can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.
```

In your case ,I would implement like this:

```
int r;
r = scanf("%f", &visitLocation.latitude);
if (1 !=r)
{
    printf("latitude should be float.\n");
}
...
```